# Rename [edx] to [open-edx]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

As stated on [code.edx.org](http://code.edx.org):

> Welcome to edX's open source initiative – Open edX – where developers
>   around the globe are working to create a next-generation online
>   learning platform to bring quality education to students around the
>   world.

This is confusing: [**edX**](http://edx.org), a non-profit, open sourced a learning platform called [**Open edX**](http://openedx.org).

I believe the tag should say [open-edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-edx), not [edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edx).

Comment: In the mean time [tag:openedx] got created. Thoughts?