# Tag openedx versus edx

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I see [this previous but ignored question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267231/1270789) requesting changing [edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edx) to [open-edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-edx), but instead we seem to have acquired an almost identically-described [openedx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openedx). I'm not sure of the tag naming convention, but the official "Open edX" name has a space in it, so shouldn't [open-edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-edx) be the preferred long format?

As far as I can see, all three tags should be synonyms and make [open-edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-edx) the master.